# ssh.net to restart an app

Tags: vb.net, ssh

I have an app that that communicate with asterisk, asterisk hangs every hour. I am using ssh.net to restart it, it does but the sub hangs waiting for a response. how can I make it not wait on a response  .So the next time that asterisk hang I am unable to restart it via the app

```
        SSHClient_1.Connect()
        If SSHClient_1.IsConnected Then
            SSHComm = SSHClient_1.RunCommand("amportal restart") ' this restart asterisk


        End If
```

I just want it to send the command and disconnect, it does not respond to the timeout

```
SSHClient_1.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did a work around. I made it a thread then wait a few seconds and kill the thread.